# Pyside - QGridLayout addStretch option?

Tags: user-interface, stretch, qgridlayout, pyside2

I have a layout that I need the widgets pushed upwards.  I know I can do this

```
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(test_widget)
layout.addStretch()
```

and the addStretch will push all widgets to the top.  However the layout that I am using is a QGridLayout and .addSretch() does not work with the grid layout.  How would I fill in all the empty space at the bottom of my window and push all my widgets to the top with a grid layout?

Answer (score 5):

nevermind, I found the answer.  I had to to do this

```
layout.setRowStretch(row_number, 1)
```

Comment: `layout.setRowStretch(layout.rowCount(), 1)` :)